# merge files deleted from git master

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I created a branch from master so that I could work on an experimental layout. I had started the experiment in the master branch, but after I branched I didn't want it there anymore so I deleteted it from master.

I continued working on master. Now, a few commits later, I want to have my changes in master merged onto the layout branch. In the near future, I want to merge the experimental layout back to master.

I tried to checkout the layout branch and rebase master, but I got a ton of conflicts. I tried to merge master to layout, but also got conflicts since I deleted the files out of master that now live in layout.

What is the correct way to handle this? I'm a recent svn convert, new to git.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the output of `git log --all --decorate --graph --pretty=format:"%h %d %s"`

Answer (score 0):

after reading my eyes bloody I did:

```
git clone http://gitproject layouts
cd layouts
git checkout layouts
git merge master
git add path_to_conflicts
git rm path_to_other_conflicts
git commit
git push
```

That seemed to do what I wanted.